# Does white noise work for barking problem?

Tags: dogs, training, vocalizations

For stoping dogs from barking, and correct barking problem, some websites suggest the devices that produce white noise. Anyone here know if they really work?

My dog barks a lot, specially when he hears sounds from outside the house.

Answer (score 1):

There are other techniques to help teach your dog not to bark that I mentioned in [this answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/37950/what-is-the-best-way-to-correct-dog-s-barking-at-home-against-sounds-from-outsid/38129#38129), but I will speak to your specific question about white noise here.

My vet recommended brown noise over white noise because of its lower frequencies. She mentioned studies showing this type of noise being better at drowning out the stimuli the dog is hearing outside while helping to soothe and relax the dog.

From my experience, this has worked well to help calm my dog and keep him from hearing noises like cars/trucks driving by, doors shutting, etc. It won't drown out the doorbell though:)