# What is the best way to correct dog’s barking at home against sounds from outside?

Tags: dogs, training, vocalizations

What is the best way to correct dog’s barking at home against sounds from outside?

If you tried something that worked, please share it.

Comment: This is really a restatement the general "how to teach a dog not to bark except on command" question, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Positive reinforcement to diminish barking](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/positive-reinforcement-to-diminish-barking)

Answer (score 2):

I've been working with a vet behavior specialist on my dog's reactivity, including excessive barking at home to triggers from outside, so I can offer what I've learned:

Try to reduce triggers wherever possible:

- don't give your dog access to visual triggers (close blinds/curtains). I got the blinds that can be pulled up or down so I can let light in without my dog being able to look out the window.
- try to drown out audible triggers like other dogs barking, trucks driving by with sound. This can be music (something calming is always good) or even brown noise.

Try to counter-condition the dog so triggers aren't so triggering. When the dog is triggered by a sound outside that causes them to bark, redirect your dog's attention away from the trigger:

- throw a ball, grab their favorite toy
- give them a command like "touch" (also called 'hand target') where you reach out your hand to the side, and they bop their nose against your palm. After they do this, give them a treat. It's important to have your dog respond to some command here so they are doing something to earn the treat.

By doing this, you're helping your dog change their association with the truck sounds from danger to neutral or even good.